# websocket Write Close Message always send 1006

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I want to send close code to client, but It is always 1006.

I tried,

```
func ServeWs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn := Upgrade(w, r)
    msg := websocket.FormatCloseMessage(4001, "myError")
    // case 1
    conn.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, msg)

    // case 2
    //conn.WriteControl(websocket.CloseMessage, msg, time.Now().Add(time.Second))

    // case 3
    //w, err := conn.NextWriter(websocket.CloseMessage)
    //if err != nil {
    //  return
    //}
    //if _, err = w.Write(msg); err != nil {
    //  log.Println(err)
    //}
    //w.Close()

    time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
    conn.Close()
}

func Upgrade(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) *websocket.Conn{
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil
    }
    return conn
}
```

But Not worked all these cases. How can I send except 1006 to client?

I also tested Node js ws package to verify client's.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8088 });

ws.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.close(1000, 'bac');
});
```

This javascript codes worked fine.

=== Added ===

Client Codes for testing. In chrome dev tool console, paste below

```
conn = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8088/connect"); conn.onclose = function(evt){console.log("do", evt);}; conn.onerror = function(err){console.log("err", err);}; conn.onmessage = function(msg){console.log("msg", msg);};
```

Comment: The gorilla websocket code works for me, I get the expected close code in the client.
You call `Upgrade(w, r)`, but the proper signature in (latest) gorilla is `Upgrade(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, http.Header)`, typo in example or are you using some old gorilla version?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  In particular, show the code for `Upgrade`

Comment: @johlo I added my Upgrade function. Is it because nil header?
I used codes from this example https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/chat/client.go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all because the "Sleep"

```
//time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
conn.Close()
```

After removing Sleep, The code works fine.